# jQuery doing things in an order

Tags: jquery, slideup

How do I get things to run smoothly and in order based on my actions.

ie

```
var $content = $("#content");
$content.slideUp().html('');
$conten.html(from_my_ajax_request).slideDown();
```

Basically I have done an ajax request to place the content of div #content.

But running the above I can see the code come in but the slideUp does not finish before slideDown takes over. I would obviously like it to be smooth.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) isn't queued (it happens immediately, independing of the `fx` queue), so either use the [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) callback, like this:

```
$("#content").slideUp(function() { 
   $(this).html(from_my_ajax_request).slideDown(); 
});
```

This calls the `.html().slideDown()` once the `.slideUp()` is finished. *Or* [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) it, like this:

```
$("#content").slideUp().queue(function(n) { 
   $(this).html(from_my_ajax_request); n();
}).slideDown();
//or...
$("#content").slideUp().queue(function() { 
   $(this).html(from_my_ajax_request).dequeue();
}).slideDown();
```

This actually puts the `.html()` call as an `fx` queue step, and it'll execute `.slideDown()` after it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $content = $("#content");
$content.slideUp(function() {
  $content.html('');
  $content.html(from_my_ajax_request).slideDown(); 
});
```

This way you use the callback to trigger the second part of your animation when the first is completed.

[slideUp docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback to slideUp and get that to execute the next step:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Or you could use the animate call:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/